# Is there a way to change the panning balance in a listener in WebAudio?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

If I have a listener and a panner node in the following 2D arrangement

```
panner ----> listener
                |
                |
                V
```

where the arrows denote the orientation of the respective entities. The listener will mostly hear the audio out of their right ear (with some small amount in the left ear). Without changing the panner position, is there a way to modify the distribution between left and right ear (the extremeness of the stereo panning effect)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve an effect where one channel is absolutely silent in the extreme case you would have to build it on your own. But it's absolutely possible.

Jordan Eldredge recently wrote an article about how to do it: https://jordaneldredge.com/blog/implementing-a-robust-web-audio-api-balance-node/

He also implemented such an effect for his [Webamp](https://github.com/captbaritone/webamp) project: https://github.com/captbaritone/webamp/blob/master/js/media/StereoBalanceNode.js

The basic idea is to up- or down-mix the signal to strereo first with a `GainNode`. Next it gets split into two distinct channels with a `ChannelSplitterNode`. Those channels are then leveled individually with a `GainNode` for each channel before they get combined again with a `ChannelMergerNode`.